# building and using a file in one transformation

Tags: xslt-2.0

Can I build up a file and refer to it within one transformation/stylesheet?
Something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="...." >
    <xsl:result-document href="file-A.xml">
       <h2 id="a1">.....</h2>
       .....
    </xsl:result-document>

    <xsl:result-document href="file-B.xml">
          <xsl:for-each select="document( 'file-A.xml')/h2">
           ...
          <xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't use the same URL for reading and writing in a single transformation. You can however build temporary trees in memory e.g. `<xsl:variable name="a"><h2>...</h2></xsl:variable>` and then process them with apply-templates or for-each e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="$a/h2"></xsl:for-each>`.

The spec says: "[ERR XTRE1500] It is a recoverable dynamic error for a stylesheet to write to an external resource and read from the same resource during a single transformation, whether or not the same URI is used to access the resource in both cases. The optional recovery action is implementation-dependent: implementations are not required to detect the error condition. Note that if the error is not detected, it is undefined whether the document that is read from the resource reflects its state before or after the result tree is written".

So based on that it might work with some XSLT 2.0 processor. I know it doesn't work with Saxon 9.